# What do OTE mean at my offer letter?

Tags: employees

My offer letter says -- BASIC: £25,000 - £35,000, OTE; £35,000 - £45,000 open ended /achievable.
What is the meaning of this

Comment: what is the position?

Comment: Ask the people who gave you the offer or, you know, look it up.

Answer (score 5):

"BASIC: £25,000 - £35,000, OTE; £35,000 - £45,000 open ended /achievable"

That's a figure I'd expect to see in a job advertisement, not an offer letter. I'd expect a solid 'basic' number, not a range - otherwise, who decides where in that scale you fall? That should have been sorted in interviews/negotiations.

I'd expect to see something like 'Basic: £25,000, OTE; £35,000 - £45,000 open ended /achievable"

So; you're guaranteed a £25,000 salary (initially, at least). If you make the number of sales that they expect ('On Target Earnings'), you'll pick up around another £10,000 - £20,000 in commission (this sounds like a sales position). 'open ended / achievable' means that there is no limit on your commission, so if you make enough sales, you can get into six figures - or at least over £50,000. They believe that a decent sales person can achieve this (of course, they would say that, wouldn't they).

It's worth bearing in mind that if you aren't hitting your targets (and picking up the bonuses), you won't be getting the 'Basic' part of your salary for very long; there's no room for underachievers in sales.

More importantly.. Terms like 'OTE' are very common in Sales. If this *is* a sales job, and you didn't grasp 'OTE', then I'd guess you don't have much experience. Hit all the training you can get your hands on. It's a cutthroat industry; the best people do very well, and failures fall by the wayside.

Answer (score 4):

"On Target Earnings" The salary you get when you reach your targets (as defined by the company).

[Wikipedia: "OTE"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-target_earnings)

Comment: thank you..... but can you explain this "BASIC: £25,000 - £35,000, OTE; £35,000 - £45,000 open ended /achievable".

Comment: You will get the BASIC for sure and the rest depends entirely on goals your employer will set up. (If they are achievable at all is completely depending on the company, you supervisor ...)